# How to formulate collapse in polarization subspace of a photon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, measurements, polarization, second-quantization

I am wondering how to describe the collapse of a photon state when it is measured in the polarization degree of freedom (say by a filter which let pass just one particular polarisation).

Let the free photon be in the state $$a^{\dagger}_{f,H}+a^{\dagger}_{g,V}$$ (disregarding the normalisation) where $$a^{\dagger}_{f,H} = \int \text d k \; f(k) \, a^{\dagger}_{k,H} $$ creates a horizontally polarized photon with frequency distribution $f(k)$. Now it passes the filter which means a measurement in the polarization degree of freedom took place.

For a filter where horizontally polarized survives the measurement is trivially described by $$a^{\dagger}_{f,H}+a^{\dagger}_{g,V} \;\longrightarrow\; a^{\dagger}_{f,H}$$ But this is just handwaving and not mathematics.

Of course I know the usual rule in quantum mechanics where after the collapse the state is calculated by applying the respective projector.
But in the formalism of second quantization I don't know a comparable rule and unfortunately I can't find an answer in the usual QM textbooks.

I guess one just has to find the right projector which transforms the creation operators.